# Accessing Azure Active Directory with username and password

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an azure subscription, an AD instance with admin rights.
Is it possible to access the AD via Graph API and get a list of all users ?

Note: I have already researched and came across this sample example :
  https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-Java

But this requires me to create a Java Web-App, add it to application on azure, get a client ID and secret and then authenticate.

Is there no way to authenticate (get an access token) by writing a simple command line java program using the ADAl4J library and provide AD username and password as credentials ?

For example :

```
 public static void main(String srgs[])
    {
        String authority = "https://login.windows.net/";
        String tenant = "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com" ;


        AuthenticationContext context = null;
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            context = new AuthenticationContext(authority + tenant + "/", true,
                    service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
                    "https://graph.windows.net", new ClientCredential("AD-USERNAME",
                    "AD-PASSWORD"), null);
            result = future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.getCause();
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible. AzureAD supports the OAuth Resource Owner Password Credential Grant. The ADAL SDK has recently added support for it (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.8.10804.1442-rc).

Note however that this method of auth fails when multi-factor auth is enabled for the account, or if the account is configured for federated auth to an IdP other than ADFS.

Vittorio has a good blog post about it here:

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/